# Rails 4.2 : Find Country from State name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state, country, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I just have started working on task which have state names for location. As project targeting global audience, we need to find country using their state name. Using [country_select gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) for country dropdown in project which have [countries](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) gem as its dependency, so using the same for populating states and country name.

For now to find country name from state name test implementation looks like:

```
def self.get_country(state=nil)
  unless state == nil
    ISO3166::Country.all.each do |cc|
      c = ISO3166::Country.find_country_by_alpha2(cc[1])
      c.states.each do |s|
        return c if s[1]["name"].downcase == state.downcase
      end if c.present?
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Which is too much iteration, please suggest a better of doing it or any other way. Later I'm thinking of adding these in DB as country and states for simple and fast querying.

Will appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!!

Comment: Guess am too late. You can use `gem geocoder`. Using which you can find the country as `Geocoder.search(user_state_name).first.country`.

Comment: Thanks @rAzOr, Geocoder seems to make http request from configured location service, everytime search made. which is good if put job into background to fetch and save data, for realtime usage.